# Overlay the Contents of a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to overlay 2 DIV's in my main parent DIV:
I want to overlay the the second div over on top of the first one. I have a problem overlaying it as I cannot keep it in the middle of the screen.
I have tried this to overlay:

The overlay works fine here, but my container is no longer center when I do this. How can I overlay and keep it center ?

```css
div {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
#first {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-color: orange;
}
#second {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container text-center">
  <div id="first">Hi</div>
  <div id="second">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do (see width of both divs and text-align properties):

You can give them background color to see z-index works perfectly :)

```css
#first {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#second {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container text-center">
  <div id="first">Hi</div>
  <div id="second">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you position absolute, the positioned element is taken out of the document flow and positioned relative to the next highest parent element that is not the default position, i.e. not position: static;

The following will cause the absolute positioned children to stay within the containing div:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That will not work, the container will collapse (all its content is positioned absolutely).

Comment: Very true, I had forgotten this.

Comment: I found this very helpful - I didn't realise that a position: static parent div would be ignored by position: absolute

Answer (score 0):

Your container's text is no longer centered because you have removed its children from the document flow. In essence, it has no content and collapses, and therefore, has no width to which to align the text.

One thing you could do is set the container to `position: relative` and full-width (i.e. `width: 100vw`), then set its children to `width: 100%`.
Then the inner `div`s will take on the width of their parent.

[See this working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbbgdgu5/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#first{
    position: absolute;
}
#second{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container"> 
    <div id="first">Hi</div>
    <div id="second">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that the `div`s will not have any relative width to the parent div.

Therefore the text is still technically "centered" in each corresponding div because they're inheriting `text-align: center` from the `container` div.

However, the divs' widths will automatically be as wide as they needs to be (i.e. to fit the text, in this case).

---

You can remedy this one of two ways:

**Force the divs to be centered**

Give both divs the following (extra) CSS:

```
left: 50%;
width: 100%;
margin-left: -50%;
```

This will literally center them in their parent div.

---

or

**Force the divs to be the same size as their parent**

Give both the divs the following (extra) CSS:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

This sets the divs to span their entire parent's height and width.

---

**In both situations**, you *might* need to make the `.container` class use `position: relative`, in order for the child divs to have something to be `absolute` to.

If you're using Bootstrap, there is no need to worry about this, as `.container` class already has this applied.

---

Hope one of these solutions helps you :)

Comment: What about setting the container to `position: relative`, setting its width and then each of the children setting `width: 100%`? (See my answer.)

Comment: You're right, you can do that also. This just provides an alternative, so the OP can make an informed decision - there's no point everybody posting the same answer!

Comment: Absolutely agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this style:

```
#first,
#second {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
#first {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-color: orange;
}
#second {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-color: green;
}
#first,
#second {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container text-center">
  <div id="first">Hi</div>
  <div id="second">Hello</div>
</div>
```